# Is it possible to perform hibernation task in the background and keep computer turned on?

Tags: hibernate, windows-11

The idea is to make Windows (version 11) perform the hibernation task in the background by saving all open sessions into the `Hiberfil.sys` file every x minutes but do not turn the computer off or interrupt anything, so that if a power outage happens, user will always have their work saved from x minutes ago on the SSD.

is this possible to do? if so how and if it's not, why not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can not work because the the NTFS file system state is included in hibernate file and all the opened and modified files would not match the state saved in hibernate file. This is the reason working with an alternate os on a system in hibernation state is so dangerous and can cause massive damage to your file-system.

Comment: @Robert I think VSS (Volume Shadow Copy Service) can fix that, no?

Comment: I am not sure if VSS goes that deep into NTFS that it preserves the IDs the file handles in the kernel base on. If you want to save RAM persistently it is better to use one of the flash memory systems that automatically save RAM state to their flash e.g. in case of a power outage (this subsystem has it's own battery to preserver RAM state until it is copied completely to flash memory. Such systems are available for server systems.

Comment: As Robert said this is impossible in Windows, but you CAN run a guest Virtual Machine and use snapshots (with VirtualBox for example)